# Need of Extrinsic parameter Camera calibration tips

Tags: camera-calibration

I am new to camera calibration (Extrinsic Parameters)..please give clear idea how to start with extrinsic parameters computation. I really need some answers.. am in critical position.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Camera Calibrator app](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/single-camera-calibrator-app.html) in MATLAB.